# "Le verbe trouver se conjugue au subjonctif quand il sert de complément au verbe pouvoir."

Tags: subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Je suis en train de corriger une phrase et je ne parviens pas à déterminer quelle est la forme correcte.

> Il se pourrait toutefois que d’autres technologies dans ces langages
>   soient davantage adaptées à la situation et que je ne les ai**e** tout
>   simplement pas trouvées, de plus amples recherches me semblent
>   nécessaires si vous souhaitez envisager d’utiliser ces technologies
>
> Il se pourrait toutefois que d’autres technologies dans ces langages
>   soient davantage adaptées à la situation et que je ne les ai tout
>   simplement pas trouvées, de plus amples recherches me semblent
>   nécessaires si vous souhaitez envisager d’utiliser ces technologies

J'ignore si je dois utiliser "aie" ou "ai", d'après mon correcteur (Antidote) je devrais utiliser "aie", mais Word ne reconnais pas cette forme (j'ai davantage confiance en Antidote de toute manière). Seulement même en cherchant je ne sais toujours pas laquelle est correcte.

D'après Antidote :

*"Le verbe trouver se conjugue au subjonctif quand il sert de complément au verbe pouvoir."*

Comment: D'après moi, la forme correcte est **aie** mais j'aimerais confirmation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Il se pourrait que* est toujours suivi du subjonctif. Cet exemple est très pratique parce qu'il permet à un locuteur natif de comprendre qu'il faut utiliser le subjonctif *aie*. *Avoir* est mis au subjonctif pour la même raison que *être* dans l'autre subordonnée: « que d'autres technologies *soient* davantage adaptées … et que je ne les *aie* … ».

Answer (score 1):

La forme du subjonctif présent 1SG s'écrie normalement *j'aie* comme vous pouvez le vérifier sur tous les sites de [conjugaison](http://www.conjugaison.com/conjuguer.php?verbe=avoir&x=0&y=0) classiques...